# Left justifying the "remember me" checkbox in simpleform + bootstrap in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I want my "remember me" checkbox to be aligned to the left like a normal checkbox.

But currently, it's super wide and centered, due to the `.form-control` class.

[Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example) shows that the output html needs to be

```
<form role="form">
  ...
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

But the output instead is

I adjusted my simpleform initializers, but I'm not sure which one I need to adjust further to get the desired behavior.

**The output html**

```
<form id="new_user" class="simple_form new_user" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<div class="form-group boolean optional user_remember_me">
    <label class="boolean optional control-label" for="user_remember_me">

        Remember me

    </label>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[remember_me]"></input>
    <label class="">
        <input id="user_remember_me" class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[remember_me]"></input>
    </label>
    <div class="controls"></div>
</div>
```

Here are the actual files:

devise **new.html.slim**

```
h2 Sign in
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, "Sign in"
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

**simple_form.rb**

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # Wrappers are used by the form builder to generate a
  # complete input. You can remove any component from the
  # wrapper, change the order or even add your own to the
  # stack. The options given below are used to wrap the
  # whole input.
  config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
    hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
    ## Extensions enabled by default
    # Any of these extensions can be disabled for a
    # given input by passing: `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => false`.
    # You can make any of these extensions optional by
    # renaming `b.use` to `b.optional`.

    # Determines whether to use HTML5 (:email, :url, ...)
    # and required attributes
    b.use :html5

    # Calculates placeholders automatically from I18n
    # You can also pass a string as f.input placeholder: "Placeholder"
    b.use :placeholder

    ## Optional extensions
    # They are disabled unless you pass `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => :lookup`
    # to the input. If so, they will retrieve the values from the model
    # if any exists. If you want to enable the lookup for any of those
    # extensions by default, you can change `b.optional` to `b.use`.

    # Calculates maxlength from length validations for string inputs
    b.optional :maxlength

    # Calculates pattern from format validations for string inputs
    b.optional :pattern

    # Calculates min and max from length validations for numeric inputs
    b.optional :min_max

    # Calculates readonly automatically from readonly attributes
    b.optional :readonly

    ## Inputs
    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
  end

  # The default wrapper to be used by the FormBuilder.
  config.default_wrapper = :default

  # Define the way to render check boxes / radio buttons with labels.
  # Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
  #   inline: input + label
  #   nested: label > input
  config.boolean_style = :nested

  # Default class for buttons
  config.button_class = 'btn'

  # Method used to tidy up errors. Specify any Rails Array method.
  # :first lists the first message for each field.
  # Use :to_sentence to list all errors for each field.
  # config.error_method = :first

  # Default tag used for error notification helper.
  config.error_notification_tag = :div

  # CSS class to add for error notification helper.
  config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-error'

  # ID to add for error notification helper.
  # config.error_notification_id = nil

  # Series of attempts to detect a default label method for collection.
  # config.collection_label_methods = [ :to_label, :name, :title, :to_s ]

  # Series of attempts to detect a default value method for collection.
  # config.collection_value_methods = [ :id, :to_s ]

  # You can wrap a collection of radio/check boxes in a pre-defined tag, defaulting to none.
  # config.collection_wrapper_tag = nil

  # You can define the class to use on all collection wrappers. Defaulting to none.
  # config.collection_wrapper_class = nil

  # You can wrap each item in a collection of radio/check boxes with a tag,
  # defaulting to :span. Please note that when using :boolean_style = :nested,
  # SimpleForm will force this option to be a label.
  # config.item_wrapper_tag = :span

  # You can define a class to use in all item wrappers. Defaulting to none.
  # config.item_wrapper_class = nil

  # How the label text should be generated altogether with the required text.
  # config.label_text = lambda { |label, required| "#{required} #{label}" }

  # You can define the class to use on all labels. Default is nil.
  config.label_class = 'control-label'

  # You can define the class to use on all forms. Default is simple_form.
  # config.form_class = :simple_form

  # You can define which elements should obtain additional classes
  # config.generate_additional_classes_for = [:wrapper, :label, :input]

  # Whether attributes are required by default (or not). Default is true.
  # config.required_by_default = true

  # Tell browsers whether to use the native HTML5 validations (novalidate form option).
  # These validations are enabled in SimpleForm's internal config but disabled by default
  # in this configuration, which is recommended due to some quirks from different browsers.
  # To stop SimpleForm from generating the novalidate option, enabling the HTML5 validations,
  # change this configuration to true.
  config.browser_validations = false

  # Collection of methods to detect if a file type was given.
  # config.file_methods = [ :mounted_as, :file?, :public_filename ]

  # Custom mappings for input types. This should be a hash containing a regexp
  # to match as key, and the input type that will be used when the field name
  # matches the regexp as value.
  # config.input_mappings = { /count/ => :integer }

  # Custom wrappers for input types. This should be a hash containing an input
  # type as key and the wrapper that will be used for all inputs with specified type.
  # config.wrapper_mappings = { string: :prepend }

  # Default priority for time_zone inputs.
  # config.time_zone_priority = nil

  # Default priority for country inputs.
  # config.country_priority = nil

  # When false, do not use translations for labels.
  # config.translate_labels = true

  # Automatically discover new inputs in Rails' autoload path.
  # config.inputs_discovery = true

  # Cache SimpleForm inputs discovery
  # config.cache_discovery = !Rails.env.development?

  # Default class for inputs
  # config.input_class = nil

#

  # Default class for inputs
  config.input_class = 'form-control'
end
```

**simple_form.bootstrap.rb**

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end


  # Wrappers for forms and inputs using the Twitter Bootstrap toolkit.
  # Check the Bootstrap docs (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)
  # to learn about the different styles for forms and inputs,
  # buttons and other elements.
  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap
end
```

UPDATE:

Updated simple_form gem version to `3.1.0.rc1` as pointed out by the accepted answer. After running `rails g simple_form:install` and rails g simple_Form:install --bootstrap`, the new config initializer files are updated. My html output is much better, but with the small detail of the checkbox being vertical, rather than inline. The output is the following:

```
<div class="form-group boolean optional user_remember_me">

    <label class="boolean optional control-label" for="user_remember_me">

        Remember me

    </label>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[remember_me]"></input>
        <label>
            <input id="user_remember_me" class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[remember_me]"></input>
        </label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you post the styles applied on checkbox?

Comment: there's nothing except for bootstrap and simple form

Comment: If you visit http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms and look at the **Check me out** checkbox in that form...is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes! that's exactly it. So the trick would be to generate that html output with simpleform settings somehow.

Comment: `= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: true`. Does this work for you? btw, this is HAML. Please adjust accordingly. Make sure you **don't** has `form-control` as the default input class. Bootstrap does not intend for you to use `form-control` on your checkboxes.

Comment: Found this. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers

Comment: @gwho do you any link of your app where i could see it and adjust styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until `simple_form 3.1.0.rc1` there was no support for bootstrap 3 markup with simple_form. So the generated HTML contains mixed bootstrap 2 and 3 classes. The correct markup for bootstrap 3 should look like

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class="boolean input optional checkbox" id="user_remember_me_input">
        <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <label class=" control-label" for="user_remember_me">
            <input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is 3.1.0.rc1 the latest version so far? They don't seem to specify this in the github page.

Comment: According to rubygems (https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_form) the latest version is 3.1.0.rc2 . If you don't specify a version in your Gemfile you'll get 3.0.2, which seems to be the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you added a default input class of `form-control` for all inputs. This means it will add that class to inputs such as `checkbox` and `select` which you might not want. Bootstrap does not intend for you to use `form-control` on your checkboxes. You can still keep this settings if you want, you just need to override the class in your form for specific inputs like `checkbox`.

```
= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: true, input_html: { class: 'something-other-than-form-control' }
```

Does this work for you? btw, this is HAML. Please adjust accordingly.

Comment: Not quite, not with my settings. 

Is there a way to add an exception for `checkboxes` and `selects` in the config initalizer files?